# odd matrix operation

Tags: matrix, vector, operators

This is for the case of a 10 x 10 matrix.

I have the matrix
`raise =
  {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {Sqrt[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, Sqrt[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, Sqrt[4], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[5], 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[6], 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[7], 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[8], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    Sqrt[9]}};`

`lower =
  {{0, Sqrt[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, Sqrt[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[4], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[5], 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[6], 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[7], 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[8], 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Sqrt[9]},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};`

They are the matrix representation of the raising and lowering operators, respectively. 
[image]

I am told that

`N[raise.lower]` must yield a diagonal matrix.

Nothing I have done here seem to suggest I am doing anything wrong. In fact, I have went through the entries for the past one hour and it feels rather frustrating. 
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `MatrixForm[raise]` to see the typo.

Comment: Try `raise = DiagonalMatrix[Sqrt[Range[9]], -1, 10]; raise.Transpose[raise]`

Comment: I have spotted the error. I think @J.M. has a foolproof method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `raise`  matrix has an error. In addition to [`DiagonalMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiagonalMatrix.html) (as per J.M.), particularly useful in this case, you can also use [`Band`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html):

```
l = SparseArray[Band[{1, 2}] -> Table[Sqrt[j], {j, 9}], {10, 10}];
r = SparseArray[Band[{2, 1}] -> Table[Sqrt[j], {j, 9}], {10, 10}];
Row[ArrayPlot[#, Mesh -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> # /. {r -> "Raising", l -> "Lowering", r.l -> "r.l"},
     ImageSize -> 200] & /@ {r, l, r.l}]
```

[image]